# Unsigned number ruby

Tags: ruby

I want a variable to hold a number that can't be assigned a negative number, so that `myvar = -1` would just end up being `0`. I can easily make my own class to do this, but does ruby already come with one?

Answer (score 2):

You'll need a custom class to do it. Since Ruby is dynamically typed, you can't prevent a particular variable from holding a negative integer, or even a string for that matter.

Answer (score 2):

No, you'll need to handle validation of the value on your own. Here's more info on the different ruby numerical types: http://www.techotopia.com/index.php/Ruby_Number_Classes_and_Conversions